# Why do I have this IP ERROR when doing Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, architecture

I am trying to do Docker Compose for a project, but when I try to do it the connection to the RabbitMQ network does not work, but this only happens if I do Compose, since if I run the separate Containers the connection is made successfully.

THIS IS MY DOCKER-COMPOSE.YML

```
version: '3'

services:
  notification:
    image: jyarac/notification_ms
    container_name: notification-microservice
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    networks: 
      - rabbit_mq_nf
  gps:
    image: jyarac/gps
    container_name: gps-microservice
    ports: 
      - "3001:3001"
    networks: 
      - rabbit_mq_nf
  mq_ms:
    image: jyarac/mq_ms
    container_name: rabbit-microservice
    ports: 
      - "3005:3005"
    networks: 
      - rabbit_mq_nf
  rabbit_ms: 
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports: 
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    networks:
      - rabbit_mq_nf

networks:
  rabbit_mq_nf:
    driver: bridge

AND THE ERROR IS
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.25.0.5:5672
2023-10-02 19:18:04     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16) {
2023-10-02 19:18:04   errno: -111,
2023-10-02 19:18:04   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2023-10-02 19:18:04   syscall: 'connect',
2023-10-02 19:18:04   address: '172.25.0.5',
2023-10-02 19:18:04   port: 5672
2023-10-02 19:18:04 }
```

Comment: Which container is producing that error?  How is it configured to connect to the RabbitMQ broker?  Are you hitting the problem described in [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) where the application starts before RabbitMQ is ready?

Comment: (I might delete _all_ of the `networks:` and `container_name:` options; Compose has reasonable defaults for these, and they're a large fraction of your file.  If you want to persist RabbitMQ's storage to disk, unusually, you do need to set a `hostname:` for that specific container, along with the more normal `volumes:`.)

Comment: It might be a timing issue where compose brings up the services so fast that your services try to connect to RabbitMQ before it's ready to accept connections. Adding `depends_on` to your compose file might help, but it might not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I have this IP ERROR when doing Docker Compose?

You need to update your application to connect to the RabbitMQ container using its service name - **rabbitmq** instead of its IP address.

To do this, you need to change the connection string in your application configuration file. If you use Node.js, you need to change the AMQP_URI environment variable to `amqp://rabbitmq:5672`.

After that I hope you will be able to connect to the RabbitMQ container successfully.

Let me know if it work for you.

Comment: This configuration doesn't work yet :C but thanks for the help.